# Unable to save NXT program

Tags: nxt, nxt-g

I pulled out my NXT recently to tinker around with it. After reconstructing one of the suggested builds, I was writing a small program for it. About halfway through, I needed to leave my work, so I tried to save the file, but I was unable to. I received the following completely straightforward and not confusing error message:

[image: error message]

The text of the error message reads

`Insane object at BHDP+3C18 in "Arm4Caleb.rbt": {graphics } (0x80): Loop Tunnel DCO )`

with Arm4Caleb.rbt being the name of the file. I have failed to find what this error message may be referring to.

I also attempted to save a blank NXT program file; this was successful, leading me to believe that there was something wrong with my particular program. Consequently, I attach an image of the NXT program (I can't post the file because I can't save it):

[image: program]

The program is in collapsed mode so that I can screenshot it; the alternate decision for the largest switch "box" is a use of the C motor; the alternate decision for the medium box is a use of the C motor in the opposite direction; the alternate decision for the smallest box is doing nothing.

It's been a while since I've tried this visual coding stuff; I suppose I have an error somewhere in here? I'm not sure why it would prevent me from at least saving the file, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, all that I was missing was a `STOP` block at the end of the thread. Hopefully my oversight helps future users.

The `STOP` block looks like so:

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of correct program with a "STOP" block to include in your answer?

Comment: @Alex do you think a picture of just the STOP block would work?